# Questions about Hebrew

Tags: discussion

What should be done with questions about irrelevant languages, such as [Hebrew](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-does-this-russian-word-mean#comment3898_1486)? Perhaps they should be migrated to [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), since there is not a `Hebrew Language and Usage` site.

Comment: This is Hebrew alphabet, and the question is an attempt in trolling. Closing should be done with such questions, what else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the question. If the question had been a good one, yes, you could have migrated it, but the question was a poor request of translation.

When you see poor questions, don't be afraid to flag them, we'll take care of the rest. If you have enough reputation vote to close. If the question is spam or seriously problematic, also flag it, just in case.

By the way, that question has nothing that would make it good on Linguistics SE.